# .off does not unbind a previously bound event

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, jquery-events

I have a modal dialog that when shown, bind a click event to a button. When that modal dialog is hidden, that event should be unbind.

To accomplish that, I am doing this:

```
let register = jQuery('#registerData')
        .modal({backdrop: 'static'})
        .modal('show');
register.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    jQuery('#regAddStudent').on('click', function () {
        console.log('agregó');
    });
});
register.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log('pasó');
    jQuery('#regAddStudent').off('click');
});
```

When dialog is closed, the `hidden.bs.modal` event is called. When the modal dialog is opened again, and press the `regAddStudent` button, the `click` handler is called twice, meaning that the `.off` call did not work.

What is wrong?

Comment: i would try the event `hide.bs.modal` which runs before the modal disappears completely.

Comment: @ITgoldman I tried it already

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be reproduced. The error is somewhere else. Notice that using this code, the first time the modal is opened the button *shouldn't* work because the modal is opened before the event is listened. So you're probably opening the modal twice.

```js
let register = jQuery('#registerData')
  .modal({
    backdrop: 'static'
  })
  .modal('show');
register.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  jQuery('#regAddStudent').on('click', function() {
    console.log('agregó');
  });
});
register.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  console.log('pasó');
  jQuery('#regAddStudent').off('click');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerData">
  Launch demo modal
</button>


<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="registerData">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"> <button></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="regAddStudent" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">regAddStudent</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```